# log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database connection []

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, log4net

I am initializing the connection string dynamically for log4net in a vb.net project like below inside the startup.vb, where am also configuring the log4net before connection string initialization,

```vb
Dim rep As log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
If rep Is Nothing Then
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("Unable to get log4net Repository.")
Else
    For Each adoNetAppender As log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender In                                                                       
        rep.GetAppenders().OfType(Of log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender)()
        adoNetAppender.ConnectionString = 
            DataAccess.GetConnectionString(DataAccess.DBInstance.ICPS)
        adoNetAppender.ActivateOptions()
    Next
End If
```

The appender is also picking up the right DB instance credentials (in DB instance the project is ran), but when I run the application it's throwing the below error and details are not getting inserted into the table,

> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database connection []. Connection string context [Unable to resolve connection string from ConnectionString, ConnectionStrings, or AppSettings.].
> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.PermissionDemand()
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
> at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.InitializeDatabaseConnection()

But when I gave the same credentials within the connection string tag inside the log4net.config file, it's working fine and inserting the details into the table

Find my log4net.config file configuration below ,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, 
         System.Data.OracleClient, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, 
                      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <!--<connectionString value="Data Source=ICD3.WORLD; User Id=icpsuser; Password=icpsusr; Persist Security Info=True; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=1; Max Pool Size=50"/> -->
    <!-- Connection string is dynamically defined inside startup.vb-->
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO ICPSOWNER.DEBUG_LOG (SEQ_NBR, INSERT_DATE, ACTIVITY, 
ACTIVITY_DETAIL) VALUES (DEBUG_LOG_SEQ.NextVal, sysdate, :Log_Method, :Log_Message)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":Log_Method" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%method" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":Log_Message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="1000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Let me know if am missing out anything and why the dynamic initialization of connection string while the explicit declaration of same connection string parameters are working fine

[image: Connection string parameters]